# Edge Screen nav drawer button show white box android

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

[Nav bar hamburger Button show white box][it only happens on curve screen like Samsung s8 s9 etc works fine on plain screen]

this is a screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

```
private void getViewsReference() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityAppBar);
    drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
}

private void setAppBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu); //working
}
```

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: please add screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiqCp.jpg 
please check screenshot at this url Suraj and Ashish

Comment: did you find anything? regarding this to solve this issue.

Comment: unfortunately nothing on internet yet.

Comment: Please edit your question. add some related code. show another device screenshot as well. I'll try to understand code.

Comment: @AshishKudale i have edited the question as you can see now other device have same android version P but its a flat screen and it works perfect on it.

Comment: are you using jetpack

Comment: @skryshtafovych no